# how to find when Image src was loaded fulfill

Tags: jquery, image, load, promise

When i use promise function for sure that my Image is loaded or not, then just when img tag was loaded and before load Image src, this method show my alert. I like find when my Image is Load fulfill, what's way for fix this problem?

```
$('#Image').promise().done(function() {
  alert("Loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[load](http://jsfiddle.net/xHQ6D/)** for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imageLoaded = function() {
    alert('21')
}
$('#img1').each(function() {
    var tmpImg = new Image() ;
    tmpImg.onload = imageLoaded ;
    tmpImg.src = $(this).attr('src') ;
}) ;
}) ;
```

Comment: thanks, but i use that, when Image is loaded in frist time, it's work truly but when in second time page is refreshed Image load not works becuse Image in second time saved on client side and load() function not works

Comment: @MojtabaSh: Updated the answer. please check.